# N+1 запрос в SerializerMethodField

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-orm

`view`

```
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Good]:
        ....
        qs = (
            Good.objects.values('brand_id', 'brand__name')
            .annotate(
                ....
            )
            .prefetch_related(Prefetch('history', StocksHistory.objects.filter(Q(**subquery_filter_args))))
            .order_by('-total_sales')
        )
        return qs
```

`serializer`

```
class ExtendedBrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    history = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Good
        fields = (
            ...
            'history',
        )

    def get_history(self, good: dict) -> dict:
      ....

      return StocksHistorySerializer(
        StocksHistory.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( snap_at )'})
        .values('day')
        .filter(history_filter_query)
        .annotate(
            ....
        ),
        many=True,
      ).data
```

**Relation**: `StocksHistory (*) -> (1) Good`.

В логах вижу `N+1` запрос в `SerializerMethodField`. Как можно пофиксить?

Возможно, есть вариант вынести `annotate` с сериалайзера во вьюху?

Суть в том, что в ответе мне нужен ключ `history`, в котором будет список объектов "дочерних" элементов?

Возможно, есть у кого идеи, как это на RAW SQL переписать?

**UPDATE:**

На данный момент я сделал это с двумя запросами и вручную объединил 2 кверисета в нужную мне результат, но мне такое решение как-то совсем не нравится.

**view**

```
    def get_queryset(self) -> QuerySet[Good]:
        subquery_filter_args = {}
        history_filter_args = {}
        if all([key in self.request.query_params for key in ['history_from_date', 'history_to_date']]):
            from_date, to_date = get_history_date_range(request=self.request)
            subquery_filter_args.update({'snap_at__range': (from_date, to_date)})
            history_filter_args.update({'history__snap_at__range': (from_date, to_date)})
        history_filter_query = Q(**history_filter_args)

        qs = (
            Good.objects.values('brand_id', 'brand__name')
            .annotate(
                total_sales=Sum('history__sales', filter=history_filter_query),
                avg_sales_per_day=Avg('history__sales', filter=history_filter_query),
                total_revenue=Sum('history__revenue', filter=history_filter_query),
                avg_revenue_per_day=Avg('history__revenue', filter=history_filter_query),
                rating=Avg('history__rating', filter=history_filter_query),
                feedbacks=Sum('history__feedbacks', filter=history_filter_query),
                base_price=Avg('history__base_price', filter=history_filter_query),
                price=Avg('history__price', filter=history_filter_query),
                price_with_discount=Avg('history__price_with_discount', filter=history_filter_query),
                discount=Avg('history__discount', filter=history_filter_query),
                max_price=Max('history__price', filter=history_filter_query),
                min_price=Min('history__price', filter=history_filter_query),
                avg_price=Avg('history__price', filter=history_filter_query),
            )
            .prefetch_related(Prefetch('history', StocksHistory.objects.filter(Q(**subquery_filter_args))))
            .order_by('-total_sales')
        )
        return qs

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            data = serializer.data
            add_histories_to_top_response(request=self.request, data=data)
            response = self.get_paginated_response(data)
            return response

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        add_histories_to_top_response(request=self.request, data=data)
        return Response(data)
```

**helper**

```
def add_histories_to_top_response(request: Request, data: OrderedDict):
    history_filter_args = {'good__brand__in': tuple(item['brand_id'] for item in data)}
    if all([key in request.query_params for key in ['history_from_date', 'history_to_date']]):
        from_date, to_date = get_history_date_range()
        history_filter_args.update({'history__snap_at__range': (from_date, to_date)})
    history_filter_query = Q(**history_filter_args)

    histories = StocksHistorySerializer(
        StocksHistory.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( snap_at )'})
        .values('day')
        .filter(history_filter_query)
        .annotate(
            sales=Sum('sales', filter=history_filter_query),
            feedbacks=Sum('feedbacks', filter=history_filter_query),
            rating=Avg('rating', filter=history_filter_query),
            base_price=Avg('base_price', filter=history_filter_query),
            price=Avg('price', filter=history_filter_query),
            price_with_discount=Avg('price_with_discount', filter=history_filter_query),
            revenue=Avg('revenue', filter=history_filter_query),
            stock_balances=Avg('stock_balances', filter=history_filter_query),
            snap_at=TruncDay('snap_at', filter=history_filter_query),
        )
        .values(
            'snap_at',
            'feedbacks',
            'rating',
            'price',
            'base_price',
            'price_with_discount',
            'sales',
            'revenue',
            'stock_balances',
            'good__brand_id',
        ),
        many=True,
    ).data

    set_histories(data, histories)


def set_histories(data: OrderedDict, histories: OrderedDict):
    for item in data:
        item['history'] = []
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(histories, lambda x: x['brand_id']):
            if item['brand_id'] == key:
                item['history'] = list(group)


def get_history_date_range(request: Request) -> tuple[datetime, datetime]:
    _date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'

    from_date = datetime.strptime(request.query_params['history_from_date'], _date_format).replace(tzinfo=utc)
    to_date = datetime.strptime(request.query_params['history_to_date'], _date_format).replace(tzinfo=utc)
    return from_date, to_date
```

Comment: `get_history` берется для каждого из объектов. попробуйте брать историю из `good`, который должен быть объектом, для которого создавали сериализатор. т.е `good.history` примерно

Comment: @ZaArs вместо `StocksHistory.objects.extra` в SerilizerMethodField что-то по типу `good.history.extra`?

Comment: ` extra` вынести в `Prefetch` в `get_queryset`. Вам надо получить все заранее, а в `get_history` только отдавать.

Если одни запросом никак не получается, то как вариант можно переопределить `filter_queryset` и модифицировать объект, или бэкэнд написать. Второй вариант распишу подробнее если не получится первый

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую

Comment: @ZaArs прокинул `extra` в `Prefetch` - в итоге в `SerializerMethodField` прилетает словарь, в котором есть ключ `history`, значение у которого число `int` (похоже, айди какой-то)

Comment: Мне можно и двумя запросами, в принципе. Главное, чтобы не N+1 , и не такой костыльный вариант, как я сделал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Второй вариант, который должен сработать, если не получается сделать одним запросом.

Указываете класс, определенный ниже, в `filter_backends` вашей вьюхи, он должен стоять в самом конце.

```
from rest_framework.filters import BaseFilterBackend


class HistoryFilterBackend(BaseFilterBackend):
    
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        """
        Return a filtered queryset.
        """
        secondary_queryset = queryset.model.history.all().filter(id__in=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))
        secondary_data_dict = {x.good_id: x for x in secondary_queryset}  # Под вопросом, требуются правки, информация
        
        new_queryset = []
        for x in queryset:
            # <param_name> - название поля, в котором будет храниться доп инфа
            if x.id in secondary_data_dict:
                setattr(x, '<param_name>', secondary_data_dict[x.id])  
            else:
                setattr(x, '<param_name>', None)
            new_queryset.append(x)
        
        return new_queryset
```

Правда вероятно, сломается пагинация, но думаю это легко решить, создав фейковый queryset. Пока ответить про qs не могу, надо подумать. Дополню при появлении доп информации

Тогда сериализатор должен будет выглядеть следущим образом

```
class ....(...):

    history = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_history(self, obj):
        """
        obj - это что поместили в <param_name>. Если поместили словарь - будет словарь.
        """
        # что то делаем
        return result  # любое словарь/значение/данные сериализатора и тд
```

Comment: Хотя можно таким же образом сделать пагинатор. тогда не нужно думать о queryset е, но это логически неверно будет

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что вы здесь делаете селект таблици `hisotory` 
 по связанной записи? `queryset.model.history.all().filter(id__in=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True))` Тогда нужно `good_id__in=queryset.values_list('id', flat=True)` , так понимаю.

Comment: Да. Делаем выборку истоии и того, что нам нужно для уже отфильтрованного набора объектов.

Comment: Дальше в цикле `for x in queryset:` вы перебираете кверисет основной таблицы и если айди её есть в `secondary_queryset` (таблице `history`) , то добавляете в кверисет в поле `history` объект истории? Кажется, это несовсем корректно.

Comment: Наверное, `secondary_data_dict = {x.good_id: x for x in secondary_queryset}` должно быть как-то так

Comment: Но нет. Если у нескольких объектов будет один и тот же `good_id` - словарь не подойдёт

Comment: В общем, с этим понятно, разберусь. А как должен выглядеть сериалайзер (интересует поле `history`)?

Comment: да, но тогда, надо учесть что объектов много. что вы получаете в запросе `StocksHistory.objects.extra(select={'day': 'date( snap_at )'})` ?? Какие данные, пример?

Comment: Не могу отредактировать пост. Вот модель. Делай группировку по полю snap_at, по дням/неделям/месяцам

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dima-dmytruk23/8b1d76ebd2d7b3f758d6fae429e528ee

Comment: Начал разбираться и править под себя
`'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'`

Comment: Есть ощущение, что `queryset.model` работает не совсем так, как нам кажется

Comment: Значит, без `all()`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137547/discussion-between-m0nte-cr1st0-and-za-ars).

Comment: Да, пагинация отвалилась)

Comment: `paginator.num_pages == 1`